# HTML report generation in postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I want to generate HTML report for APIs with the help of postman application.

I want to run my collection and environment simultaneously and generate HTML report of pass and failure results.

please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

1. Install npm package newman-reporter-htmlextra for creating reports.

   `npm install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra`
2. Add parameters to the newman execution command to use this npm package to create html file(index.html) containing details of execution.

   `newman run xyz.postman_collection.json -e env.postman_environment.json -r htmlextra --reporters cli,junit,htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-export index.html`
3. Html file with detailed execution report is created in the collection folder.

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve this, you will need to run your collections with Newman, the Postman collection runner. From here you will be able to use exported collections or straight from a shareable link, created from the Postman application.

I've also created a new version of the HTML reporter that works with the Newman runner. This includes several of the features that have not been included into the official Postman version.

Feel free to check it out and download in here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman-reporter-htmlextra

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to start using Newman. This is the command line runner from postman.

[Postman Newman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collection_runs/command_line_integration_with_newman)

Also Newman has its own reporter, read about it [here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/blob/develop/README.md#configuring-reporters).

Newman runs as part of node so you can use many other tools available in node.
Now there is this tool to build an html report, personally I haven’t used it but I am sure will do the job.

https://github.com/felixdjost/newman-html-report-template-verbose/blob/master/README.md